# EF azure connection issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I have a web application with connection strings:

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="RedisConnectionString" connectionString="test.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=123,connectTimeout=100000000,syncTimeout=100000000" />
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:test.cloudapp.net,1433;Database=test;User ID=user;Password=test;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;TrustServerCertificate=True;" />      
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDM.test.csdl|res://*/EDM.test.ssdl|res://*/EDM.test.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:test.cloudapp.net,1433;initial catalog=test;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In start - app work well, but a few minutes later I have error, from

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

Here the log:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 
The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.) ---> 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Also I tried to put my connections strings in azure web application configure like this:
[image]

But there is no effect for EF connection.
For ADO net connection it works fine.

Also EF connection works fine on local machine.

**How can I configure my connection string for EF in Azure?**
Thanks!

**EDITED**: It seems, that the reason in flags :

```
Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
Connection Timeout=30;
TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Because, if added this flags to EF connection string, it seems works...

Comment: When you deploy, are you 100% that a web.config transformation is not blowing away the entity framework connection string?  Conversely, if you are doing web.config transformations, are you sure they are transforming before you publish?

Comment: So, I should to review my web.config on server (by FTP) - right?

Comment: You can review that way or find where the project places your built application before it publishes the files.  This will allow to confirm your web.config transformations are happening as you expect them to.

Comment: And what do you think about that application after restarting works fine in any time? And then, it crashed.

Comment: Are you saying it works, then crashes?  If that is the case, you may be having timeout issues between EF and SQL Azure.  We experienced some of the same issues - you should look into the RetryPolicies within EF or doing a try/catch around your EF calls.  It's hard to say since your problem seems transient.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I edited my question - I added some flags to EF connection string, and it seems to be working(1 hour passed). But I'm not sure. May be some problems will appear again in the future.

Comment: I have error again((((

Answer (score 0):

For EF connection strings in Azure the Drop down needs to be changed to custom.  I'm surprised you are not getting a Metadata error.

[image: Action String Values]